# How does an iPhone 7 take 4K and slow motion videos?

Tags: noise, sensor-size, iphone, compact-cameras

Even some good compact cameras at around $400 range cannot take a 4K and slow motion, so does an iPhone with **small sensor** that is generally prone to noise shooting 4K now?

A small sensor should always lag behind from what I have seen in terms of noise and low light capabilities.

Some people are even comparing it with DSLR cameras with ACPS and full frame sensors. How does this all make sense?

Comment: This sounds very much like a rant... What exactly is your question?

Comment: I think this is a good question. Now that it has been asked I would like to know the answer as well? How *do* iPhones take 4K slowmo? Is it software? My DSLR can't do this and probably has a nicer sensor and has much nicer lenses.

Comment: cameras that cannot record 4K video in 2017 are not "good". they are outdated :-)

Comment: Videographers who want to use cameras designed to primarily be still cameras as camcorders are not rational. They are hopeless dreamers.

Comment: So exactly how much does an iPhone 7 *really* cost compared to that $400 compact camera? That is, how much does it cost when the 24 month service contract is factored into the cost (or when you buy one at full price without a service contract if you can even do that any more)?

Comment: @10Replies Just because your DSLR does not offer you the option of doing something does not necessarily mean it is not capable of doing it.

Answer (score 3):

'4K' is a resolution, and doesn't say *anything* about quality or noise. 4K is 3840 pixels × 2160 lines = 8.3 megapixels; this is also nothing special in nowadays cameras.

The feat is to take 30 frames per seconds, and process them fast enough - and that is what the iPhone can impress with; it has a pretty fast processor (and fast enough memory).

Most DSLR are optimized for photo taking and processing, under much higher resolution, with higher dynamic range, and using a lot less light. Making a 20 MP camera process 8.3 MP of it into a video takes even more computing power than reading it from a 8.3 MP sensor, and cameras don't have such processors, also the writing on the usual SD cards is by far not as fast as internal memory in the iPhone.